# Already tired after a little writing

Tags: first-draft

I don't like writing rough drafts, preferring to edit as I write. But I seem to get tired after writing only a little, though I somewhat succeed in achieving the style that I want.

Is this because I'm not accustomed to writing so much? What should I do?

Comment: Think of writing like it's jogging. If you are out of shape, just a little exercise can leave you out of breath. But as you jog more, it would become more and more easy (but "writer's block", if you ever encounter it, is a different issue).

Answer (score 6):

Oddly enough, [mental exertion burns calories](https://time.com/5400025/does-thinking-burn-calories/), just like physical exertion --and creativity definitely counts. And just like physical exercise, it takes more out of you if you aren't used to it. Keep at it, you'll build up your mental stamina.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this because I'm not accustomed to writing so much?

Probably, if you haven't wrote much(Writ much? Writed much? Something like that, you get the idea) before, then it is understandable that you can't just sit down and write out a dozen pages of stuff. I can only do 3-4 pages in one sitting before I take a break. And thats on a good day with no distractions and a good motivator.

> What should I do?

Well, the obvious answer is to practice. I'd start there, keep writing as much as you feel you can do, and then another paragraph or two more. When you come back later, edit those last paragraphs if you feel like it needs it and continue.

If that doesn't help much, then maybe try a different practice strategy. Other than that I'm not entirely sure what would help.